# Is it possible to recover all users who used an usb stick?

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I got a USB stick. Is it possible to get some information about a user who created a file on the stick? What kind of information can I retrieve on Linux about previous uses of the stick on other computers?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the file and filesystem, but in general no you can't retrieve info about user who created the file on the stick.

Most USB sticks use a variant of the FAT filesystem for storing ownership data, and this file system does not allow for the recording of data.  About the best you can do is look at the datestamp, and, if you have a limited enough system with good enough logging you may be able to tie the file creation date with when the user was logged in (running "lastlog" from the command prompt can show recent users log in/logout history).

If you reformat the stick to use a file system with support for userids (like ext2/3/4) you will be able to see who created the file in the future.

Also, you should be aware that Linux (Unix) uses userID's to identify users. These typically differ from system to system - thus if I write the file on 1 Linux system, and look at it on another, the reported username will be incorrect if the userid is not the same across systems (as reported by the third field in "sudo getent password")